# Operations in modular arithmetic - addition, multiplication and combinations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

We have the following definition

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We define two binary operations on the set

$$\mathbb{Z}_n=\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$$

1. We call $\oplus:\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$, such that $a\oplus b=(a+b)\pmod{n}$ addition modulo $n$
2. We call $\otimes:\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$, such that $a\otimes b=(a\cdot b)\pmod{n}$ multiplication modulo $n$

My question is, can we have at the same time an addition and a multiplication modulo $n$, for example something like $g(e)\oplus b=(g(e)+b)\pmod{n}=(a\cdot e+ b)\pmod{n}$? Where $g(e)=a\cdot e$

Also, in case $x=(y+z)\pmod{n}$, then $x-y-z$ is a multiple of $n$. Could we also write $(x-y-z)\pmod{n}=x\ominus_{n}(y\oplus_{n} z)?$

Comment: Well . . . $$(\Bbb Z_n, \oplus, \otimes)$$ forms what is known as a ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triplet $(\Bbb Z_n, \oplus, \otimes)$ forms something called "the ring of integers modulo $n$," which is a [commutative ring with unity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ring_of_Integers_Modulo_m_is_Ring).

> Could we also write $(x-y-z)\pmod{n}=x\ominus_{n}(y\oplus_{n} z)?$

Yes.

Comment: So by working in this field, I could do all the operations, that I quote above. And all these fields are related to polynomials or something like this? Isn't all this theory about some relation with polynomials that can also used in cryptography?

Comment: It's not necessarily a field, @HungerLearn. I'm not sure I understand your questions. Perhaps you would be better off asking them in separate questions.

Comment: Well, you can do modular arithmetic with polynomials over a field, and for example $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field. So this modular arithmetic with polynomials, holds also for this case of the commutative ring with unity right?

Comment: No sorry, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a ring, not a field...My mistake

Comment: It is only a field if $n$ is prime. Yes, @HungerLearn, we can define polynomials over a commutative ring with unity.

Comment: Thank you for you instant responses!

Comment: You're welcome, @HungerLearn.

Comment: Is $Z_n$ an abelian group as well?

Comment: It is cyclic, @HungerLearn. All cyclic groups are abelian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132607/discussion-between-hunger-learn-and-shaun).